# adding new node at specified place using dom4j in xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

My code to insert new cred-pair at desired machine level.

```
Document insertNewNode(String loginId,String pass,String machine_name)
{
List<?> list1 = document.selectNodes("//machine/@name" );
Iterator<?> itr=list1.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
Attribute attribute=(Attribute)itr.next();
if( attribute.getValue().equals(machine_name))
{
    List<?> list1 = document.selectNodes("//machine" );
    Iterator<?> iter=list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
    Element credPairs=(Element)iter.next();
    Element credPair =credPairs.addElement("cred-pair");
    Element login =credPair.addElement("login");
    element.setText(loginId);
    Element password =credPair.addElement("password");
    element.setText(pass);

}

}
}
}
```

Original xml:

```
<credentials>
<machine name="xyz">
<cred-pairs>
<cred-pair>
<login>asad</login>
<password>12345</password>
</cred-pair>
<cred-pairs>
</machine>
<machine name="pqr">
<cred-pair>
<cred-pair>
<login>ssdas</login>
<password>12345</password>
</cred-pair>
<cred-pairs>
</machine>
</credentials>
```

**If I call insertNewNode(ggss,97653,xyz)**

Expected xml:

```
<credentials>
 <machine name="xyz">
  <cred-pairs>
   <cred-pair>
    <login>asad</login>
    <password>12345</password>
   </cred-pair>
 **<cred-pair>
    <login>ggss</login>
    <password>97653</password>
   </cred-pair>**
   <cred-pairs>
 </machine>
 <machine name="pqr">
  <cred-pair>
   <cred-pair>
    <login>ssdas</login>
    <password>12345</password>
   </cred-pair>
   <cred-pairs>
 </machine>
</credentials>
```

But I am getting output as:

```
<credentials>
 <machine name="xyz">
  <cred-pairs>
   <cred-pair>
    <login>asad</login>
    <password>12345</password>
   </cred-pair>
** <cred-pair>
    <login>ggss</login>
    <password>97653</password>
   </cred-pair>**
  <cred-pairs>
 </machine>
 <machine name="pqr">
  <cred-pair>
   <cred-pair>
    <login>ssdas</login>
    <password>12345</password>
   </cred-pair>
 **<cred-pair>
    <login>ggss</login>
    <password>97653</password>
   </cred-pair>
  <cred-pairs>**
 </machine>
</credentials>
```

Answer (score 1):

After indentation I saw, that you xml is not well-formatted. There is one `<cred-pairs>` opening tag right before `</machine>` and that's illegal at that place. May be a copy/paste error.

After you've found the correct machine name attribute you select *all* machine nodes and add the credentials to every machine node. Instead you shouldn't select attributes but the elements that qualify for the machine name:

```
List<Element> machines = document.selectNodes(String.format("//machine[@name='%s']", machine_name);
for (Element machine:machines) {
    Element credPairs=(Element)iter.next();
    Element credPair =credPairs.addElement("cred-pair");
    Element login =credPair.addElement("login");
    login.setText(loginId);
    Element password =credPair.addElement("password");
    password.setText(pass);
    machine.addElement(credPairs);    
}
```

Untested but should work (or show you the direction)